# Folder permissions in Azure web sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Just getting my head around the new Azure web sites feature and hitting my first obstacle.  I'm deploying a PHP site which writes cache data to the file system, but the app is throwing an error because the folder it wants to write to does not have write permission.  Is it possible to set permissions on folders or is this a no-no?

I can probably work round this but would like to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folder permissions cannot be set/customized. This means whatever location your app writes to should be under your site root.

Answer (score 1):

Your site can only write to locations under C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[siteName]\VirtualDirectory0 and to the %TEMP% folder.

Two caveats here:

1. Stuff can't be written directly under VirtualDirectory0, you have to create a subfolder under there and place your files in that subfolder
2. The %TEMP% folder really is temporary! If your site instance goes down for any reason and is brought back up somewhere else then everything in your %TEMP% folder will be gone. Use it only for files that really are temporary.

Comment: D:\home\site\wwwroot too it seems?

Comment: @twamley Yup. D:\Home is an alias/symbolic link for C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[siteName]\VirtualDirectory0.  It's best to use the %HOME% environment variable to access that path anyways since that'll protect you against any future changes in the path name or even an change in your site's name

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder that the app is trying to write to under the site's folder?

It's my understanding that folder permissions cannot be set/changed.  But I haven't seen anything from Microsoft that definitively says "yes" or "no" to that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [webdeploy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140816181832/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureappgallery/archive/2013/04/03/set-file-folder-permissions-for-your-content-on-azure-website-using-web-deployable-package.aspx).

However I don't think there is a way do it without manually setting up the webdeploy package - as described in the post [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureappgallery/archive/2013/04/03/set-file-folder-permissions-for-your-content-on-azure-website-using-web-deployable-package.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140816181832/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureappgallery/archive/2013/04/03/set-file-folder-permissions-for-your-content-on-azure-website-using-web-deployable-package.aspx).

Comment: I cannot go to any of the links you have given. It says: The resource you requested does not exist.

Comment: @Firnas I fixed the links using the wayback machine.