# Getting server path to image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, epplus

I'm using EPPlus (props to the devs for an awesome library) to make an Excel doc that will be downloaded in the browser. In the code that generates the Excel doc, I have a few lines that are meant to include an image file in the Excel doc.

```
Image logoImg = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/bill_logo.png"));
var logo = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("Logo", logoImg);
```

When I run the project locally on my machine, the image shows up as expected. However, when I deploy to our test environment in Azure, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\sitename\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\Images\bill_logo.png
at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
at emergePortal.Web.Controllers.BillingController.buildWorksheet(ExcelWorksheet ws, String sheetName, IEnumerable`1 lineItems) in c:\a\src\emergePortal\emergePortal.Web\Controllers\BillingController.cs:line 202
at emergePortal.Web.Controllers.BillingController.getBill(Int32 billMonth, Int32 billYear) in c:\a\src\emergePortal\emergePortal.Web\Controllers\BillingController.cs:line 106
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

What is the best way to reference this image file so that it works across environments?

Comment: Set read and write to your Images folder

Comment: I may be wrong, wouldn't be the first time, but I don't believe you can edit permissions in Azure.

Comment: you can send a ticket to Azure .
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/options/

Comment: @RameshRams Is this a problem with Azure? Is the code correct?

Comment: Yes . because i got this same problem when deployed azure . The Server.MapPath is does not working in azure .

Comment: see my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17952254/1193035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given path in the exception is the correct path to that file? If yes rights? If not, the exception is correct. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the correct path to file. I don't have visibility into the file structure of the project in Azure. I will check the rights on the file - I'm assuming I just need read rights?

Comment: After some searching around, I don't believe you can change the file permissions in Azure. Can someone correct me on that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016098/folder-permissions-in-azure-web-sites

Answer (score 0):

i got this same problem when deployed azure . The Server.MapPath is does not working in azure

i fixed this problem .but i forget which how to solved this problem.sorry

please try this code way . I think i used this code for your problem

```
// Retrieve an object that points to the local storage resource
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("localStoreTwo");

//Define the file name and path
string[] paths = { localResource.RootPath, "MyStorageTest.txt"};
String filePath = Path.Combine(paths);
```

More details see this

[Getting Your Physical Application Path in Window Azure](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/132827/Getting-Your-Physical-Application-Path-in-Window-A)

and [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.localresource.rootpath.aspx)