# What folder in asp MVC Web Sites are accessible to store and retrieve files apart from App_Data when hosted in Azure Web Sites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, blobstorage

I just finished my asp MVC 5 website that has capability to upload, display and download file. While offline, I uploaded the files to a random foldes inside the root directory like ~/assest/images etc and worked great.

Then I deployed to the windows Azure Web site service, and started to realize that the root directory is not accessible anymore. I started to do researches and found out that only App_Data is accesible to store files. Alas, it is not a good solution and we cannot retrive the file, like image, to be shown in razor view.

I also found BLOB Storage, which seems to be great, but there is no sufficent tutorial, that I could not succeed to use one. Most of them are for MVC web roles, while in my case it is MVC WEB SITES.

Now, I want to find another alternative, is there any special folder, or workaround to make one folded inside the root directory that can store files and retrieve them? in fact, my application needs only a few pictures and PDF to store.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using App_Data to store uploaded files using Azure Web Sites. You only get a limited amount of space, and if you scale your site to more instances, the uploaded files will only be available on the instance where they were uploaded!

The correct way to handle uploaded files is indeed to use Blob storage. You can use this easily from your web site. Just install the Azure .NET Storage Client Library (this is [available from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)).

There is a full tutorial on using the Azure .NET Storage Client Library at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

You can easily display uploaded images on your site by making the blob container public. Then you can link directly to an image within your blob container - it will have a URL like

> https:// *your storage account name* .blob.core.windows.net/ *your blob container name* /filename.jpg

Comment: thank you sir! Now I am confident more than ever to continue using blob storage :D

Comment: This part is not true: "the uploaded files will only be available on the instance where they were uploaded!".  When you upload files to a folder in Azure Websites they're available to all instances (unless you put them in the %TEMP% folder) immediately. Other than that I agree with you

Comment: Wait a moment, I just realised the sentence "the uploaded files will only be available on the instance where they were uploaded!" implies that we can INDEED upload files to local folders? If that is the case, would you kindly share the how-to to me? @alexwarren Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do not expect to need much storage you can store your files anywhere in your site's folder. I'm not sure why you're seeing an error if you upload files to anywhere other than APP_DATA, you should have full write access anywhere.

Contrary to some other people's comments, if you store files in your site's local storage then your files are safe against the VM going down and are instantly available to all your other instances. This is because the files are not actually being stored on the local VM, it's just an illusion. (The only exception is if you store stuff in the %TEMP% folder. That stuff is actually saved on the VM and can vanish at any time).

That said, if you expect a lot of data I/O or need a lot of storage, blob storage is the best way to go.

Comment: This is actually what surprised me sir, I thought I would be having full write access, but it turns out to be not. Is is only azure that restrict the permission or I do not know. Or is there any setting for the folder to be writable? or do I have to use relative/absolute path. I think I have been researching for all the possibilities and became so desperate that I asked for any enlightenment here. Lemme elaborate a bit: I have full access when deploying, I can use arbitrary folder like ~/assets/images but they don't let me to write anything on it after it is deployed.

Comment: Btw, if you have the knowledge storing files inside the local folder, I would be glad if you could share it. It will be beneficial to know both ways; storing in local folder and in blob storage. Thank you

Comment: I found your comment here in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016098/folder-permissions-in-azure-web-sites?rq=1 But still I can not fully get how to make it work

Comment: @AceSupriatna What happens if instead of writing to relative folder paths you try writing to the absolute path of C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[siteName]\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot?  Does it work then?  I've never had to do anything special to store files anywhere I want.  The only limitation is that you cannot place files directly under the VirtualDirectory0 folder, but you can create all the subfolders you want under there

Comment: I just randomly played with the azure website we are talking right now, and AMAZINGLY I could able to upload image this time to the local folders. Nevertheless, when I tried to upload another image in another controller, it gives an error like this:  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\assets\images\pages\product\Produk Baru.JPG' What could be the problem you think?

Comment: Apparently, I found the problem. Indeed, I can write to local folder. and the error was telling there tha path is missing. I checked the uploaded directory and indeed, some custom folder are missing, they are not pushed to the azure server. Why would that be and how to solve it? I tried to re deploy but did not work.

Comment: @AceSupriatna I'm not sure but perhaps WebDeploy does not push empty folders to Azure Websites.  You could simply check to see if the directory exists (and create it if it doesn't) before uploading images to that folder

Comment: that is exactly what I just found. VS does not upload empty folder. thanks, you have been very helpful

Comment: @AceSupriatna No prob

Answer (score 1):

I would not look to build a solution that relies on local storage for azure websites or web services. You can't scale this solution and there's a chance that the VM may get re-imaged etc.

I would look at blob storage, I restrict uploads to less than 4mb as I validate them on the server before writing them into blob storage, but you can stream it direct into storage I believe.

Here's a [Guide to uploading large files from MVC](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=893) that may help get you started.

Comment: thank you so much, you helped me. I will work hard to make this blob thing going.

Comment: The VM going down won't affect files saved on the local storage. The "local storage" is only an abstraction and the files are actually saved securely elsewhere. That's how all your instances can access the same files

Comment: Local storage is described by Microsoft as 'per instance temporary storage'. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1674.data-storage-offerings-on-the-azure-platform.aspx unless something has changed since i first tried it?